# Writing a matrix as a structure array in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I will start by saying I am by no means a programmer, and am very confused. My lecturer has said that it is often useful to write a matrix, Matlab array, as a structure. I think this is to save space not storing zeros? I am having trouble implementing this in Matlab.

If I am given a matrix:

a = [1 0 3; 0 5 6; 7 0 0]

How could I go about writing this as a structure array?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: If you want to create a structure that is just going to store a single matrix, then that is nonsense.  The additional overhead for just a single structure that stores just a single matrix isn't useful.  What do you mean by **structure** array?  Do you want to just individually store the elements as individual structure field and have an array of single elements?

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for a [**sparse**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/sparse-matrices.html) matrix rather than a **structure**?

Comment: That's exactly what I am looking for, I didn't know that term. Thanks for the link!

Comment: @beaker - OK... now that makes total sense.  I also skipped over the "save space" part.  I should have clued in that it was a sparse matrix.

Comment: Good deal, glad I could help get you going. @rayryeng - That's always the way it is for me too; that one little word that seems unimportant at first reading turns out to be the key.

Comment: @beaker - Totally.  I say make this into an answer and allow Wooster to accept your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The concept you're looking for is [**sparse**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/sparse-matrices.html) matrices.

This can not only reduce the storage required for matrices with a sufficiently high proportion of zero elements, it can also speed up operations on those matrices.

You can convert an existing full (that is, non-sparse) matrix **A** to a sparse one like so:

```
S = sparse(A);
```

Other methods of creating sparse matrices can be found [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/sparse-matrix-creation.html).